# Google chrome not connecting to internet - Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, google-chrome

Chrome suddenly stopped connecting to the internet two days ago and will not now connect. No changes of any kind were made to my Dell laptop during the time between it working and not working (about 1 hour - I was listening to music on the laptop during that time). I have uninstalled Chrome and reinstalled it from the Google website, restarted Chrome, restarted my computer but to no avail. All other internet services appear to be OK. Internet Explorer works, my client based email works. 
Google Chrome on my wife's laptop (Windows 7) which uses the same WiFi connection also works.
Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: "No changes of any kind were made to my Dell laptop" Really? Something has clearly changed. Windows updates? (patch Tuesday was two days ago). Chrome updates? What is the error from Chrome? Which version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: Which version of Chrome are you using? What do you see when you launch Chrome to make you think it isn't connecting to the internet?

Answer (score 0):

I would first open Task Manager and force close all instances of chrome.exe, then try uninstalling again.

Perhaps try using [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) using the Moderate or Advanced removal procedure. Sounds as though maybe there is some kind of configuration data being left behind. The [Revo Uninstaller Guide](http://www.revouninstaller.com/manuals/freeware/Revo%20Uninstaller%20Freeware%20Help.pdf) can help walk you through the process.